# How to make divs sink on hover and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was working on some HTML and I want to have it so that when you move your mouse over the div, it will sink about 10 px, and when clicked it will sink down completely. I've done this before with divs without any links (`<a>`) or text (`<p>`) and it worked perfectly fine. But on my website ([www.metatronaut.com](http://www.metatronaut.com)) it doesn't sink at all. In my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('tag').mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).animate({
         height: '-=20px'
   });
});
$('tag').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).animate({
       height: '+=20px'
   }); 
});
$('tag').click(function() {
   $(this).animate({
       height: '-=250px'
   });
  }); 
});
```

(The divs are 250px)

Here's how my HTML  tags are listed.

```
<td>
    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/metatronstudios">
       <div id="twitter">
          <p>Twitter</p>
       </div>
    </a>
</td>
```

And the CSS

```
div {
height:250px;
width:250px;
}
table {
margin:auto;
}
a {
font-size:24px
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#twitter {
background-color:#11CDFB;
}
```

Any idea what's going wrong? Or what tag I should put in the JS? (I've used a, div, td, and p none of which have worked.)

Thanks!

-Sam

Comment: Can you define "sink"? Move the whole div down? Make it shorter? What exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to address with this: `$('tag')` - you don't have any `<tag>` elements on the page.  Are you trying to make your div move? Then the selectors need to be `$('div').mouseenter(...)`

Comment: 'tag' is just an example. I have 'div' in there currently.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery if you're going to use it. It needs to load before any other script  that references it. The best place to load your javascript is generally just before your closing `</body>` tag. This makes for faster page load and ensures the DOM is ready for you to go and manipulate it.

So add this line before `</body>`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

You'll also need to move your own script out of the head and put it after jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 Based on @user3380708's website, it looks like jquery has been left out. The code won't work if jquery isn't included (and it must be included before the sink code (script.js)

Comment: I added it to index.html after the body tag but it still isn't working?

Comment: And moving the script as in java-script after this line?

Comment: I'm very new to J-Query :P

Comment: I made a mistake, it should go before the closing body tag (actually I don't know if it matters!). Please read new answer, it should explain things better.